# C# application maximized window

Tags: c#, window, fullscreen

First the resize window button doesn't want to work ,for some reason.

```
private void FullScreenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }
        if (this.WindowState==FormWindowState.Maximized)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
    }
```

And even if i make the form maximized from the VS form properties from this http://postimg.org/image/mmy9r7qu9/ ,the form turns into this http://postimg.org/image/kzeyrb9fb/ .What is going on?

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms?

Comment: Try changing the BorderStyle:         `this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;`

Comment: Dude can't you see that it's a custom window?It's already FormBorderStyle = None from the time i started the project.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on the Form
2. Go to it's properties
3. Find the option: "WindowState"
4. Change it to "Maximized"

You can also see an image about this option in: 
https://www.mediafire.com/view/nmnf8wcjsl1zi6z/WindowState.bmp

And you can try this for a "Button_Click":

```
private void FullScreenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }
    else
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are negating the first if-statement with the second if-statement, try using an else-if.

```
private void FullScreenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }
        else if (this.WindowState==FormWindowState.Maximized)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
    }
```

As for the Maximized sizing issue, do you have the Form's MaximumSize property set to "0,0" or some other value that could be limiting it's maximum size?

Comment: Well ,i saw that error also and i fixed it but the problem is why my buttons go on top of each other when i go into maximized window mode?